# Change button type from button to submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I just dont know how to change my buttons once clicked. All I want is to change this button

```
<input type="button" onclick="codename()" id="myButton1" value="New" class="btn" name="New" style="height: 60px; width: 90px">
```

to this button

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn2" name="Query" style="height: 60px; width: 90px">
```

once clicked.I have used the

button to enable a disabled text forms, and it works. So basically my NEW BUTTON will do 2 things: first is to enable disabled forms and button (working) AND second is to change that same button from

```
<input type="button" onclick="codename()" id="myButton1" value="New" class="btn" name="New" style="height: 60px; width: 90px">` to `<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn2" name="Query" style="height: 60px; width: 90px">
```

(not yet existing)

here is my exiting code right now:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
        function codename() {

        if(document.formname.New)
        {
        document.formname.Add.disabled=false;
        document.sapcode.SapCode.disabled=false;
        document.lanecode.LaneCode.disabled=false;
        document.soldto.SoldTo.disabled=false;
        document.soldaddress.SoldAddress.disabled=false;
        document.contactperson1.ContactPerson1.disabled=false;
        document.deliveredto.DeliveredTo.disabled=false;
        document.deliveredaddress.DeliveredAddress.disabled=false;
        document.contactperson.ContactPerson.disabled=false;
        }
        else
        {
        document.formname.Add.disabled=true;
        document.sapcode.SapCode.disabled=true;
        document.lanecode.LaneCode.disabled=true;
        document.soldto.SoldTo.disabled=true;
        document.soldaddress.SoldAddress.disabled=true;
        document.contactperson1.ContactPerson1.disabled=true;
        document.deliveredto.DeliveredTo.disabled=true;
        document.deliveredaddress.DeliveredAddress.disabled=true;
        document.contactperson.ContactPerson.disabled=true;
        }
        }
//-->
        </SCRIPT>
<div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="img">
                    <img src="dimensiondata.jpg" alt="dimension data" width="250" height="60">
                </div>
                <div id="indexno">
                    <center>Index No.</center> <input type="text" name="indexNo" size="13">
                </div>
                    <form name="formname">
                        <input type="button" onclick="codename()" id="myButton1" value="New" class="btn" name="New" style="height: 60px; width: 90px">
                        <input type="submit" disabled value="Add" class="btn1" name="Add" style="height: 60px; width: 90px">
                    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you aware you can show and hide elements on a page?

Comment: SCRIPT LANGUAGE? What the hell is that directive

Comment: yes  I am very much aware of it @Teemu so what do you think will solve this thing?

Comment: Ehh... Create two `button`s, hide "Add" button until "New" has been clicked, and then hide "New".

Comment: @Teemu I cant do that because that's not part of my colleague's instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `this` a reference of event and clicked button to the function like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="codename(event, this)" id="myButton1" value="New" class="btn" name="New" style="height: 60px; width: 90px">
```

and try the modifying your function as follows:

```
function codename(e, elm){
  if(elm.type=='button'){
    var e = e || window.event;
    if(e)
     e.preventDefault()
    elm.type='submit';
    elm.value="Save";
    elm.className= 'btn2';
    elm.name= "query";
  }
//rest of the code
}
```

Comment: i'm afraid that the code you given me does not work, the button flickers then it goes back to its original way.. it does not change to SAVE Button..

Comment: @user3819129 well [it does work](http://jsfiddle.net/urw9e/). if it doesn't work for you then it's the problem with something else in your code...

Comment: @TilwinJoy An error might occur because `var e = window.event;` is IE-only.

Comment: oh yes there's an error when I placed the `var e = window.event;` the button doesn't appear anymore once clicked, I am using google chrome as it is my default browser in my wamp server, is there anything I can do to fix the error?

Comment: @Teemu it's working fine in chrome and safari. not sure about ff, an if should fix that...

Comment: The code works when I placed that code at the bottom of the SCRIPT SECTION, but once click on the new button there's an error, the save button does not shows up. Want me to send you my whole html code @Tilwin Joy so you can test it yourself?

Comment: okay let's see that… maybe you can update this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urw9e/1/) with the rest of your code...

Comment: @Tilwin Joy I'm so sorry I dont know how to use jsfiddle haha, you can see my html code [here](http://shrib.com/95u0VuKK) and my css code [here](http://shrib.com/AdG8dXJW)

Comment: @user3819129 i found the css but the html link is empty. In a fiddle,  you can simply add your html in the top left box, css in the top right box, js in the bottom left box. and see the result in bottom right box once you click `run` button in menu,, you can save it by clicking the `save` or `update` buttons (*whichever is available*) and share the link by clicking the `share` option in mentor copying the new url appeared in title bar

Comment: @Tilwin Joy do you have an email? shrib has a limit so I cant post the whole code and when I run my code in fiddle it still does have some error, or you could pm me at seph.rojas@gmail.com then I will mail you my code, still having the same problem :(

Comment: oh I have updated the fiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/urw9e/2/) is the updated link, please take a look at it @Tilwin Joy thank you!

Comment: @user3819129 the problem is with your css, yore moving the `save` button behind the `query` buttonuth. So code is [working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/urw9e/2/embedded/result/). I think it'd be better if you re-think how you want to implement this. You might want to try something like hiding the add button and changing the attributes of `query` button instead of trying to position a button there. or maybe you can fix what you're trying to do with `z-index`, it's unto you.

Comment: @user3819129 please mark the answer as accepted if it solved the issue in question, if you come up with a new approach, you can post a new question with the entire demo and explain what you're trying to do...

Comment: @Tilwin Joy you're right! the code really works and its just a matter of tweaking my css code.. it is running smooth right now! cheers! Thank you!